# Category not found

Tags: laravel

I have a filter problem in my controller, and I can't find the category in question. I tried to make a `Categories:all()` and it finds my categories well . I don't understand why...

My controller:

```
        $category = Request::get('category');
        $productsList = array();

        $currentCategory = Category::where('slug', $category);

        dd($currentCategory, $category);
```

My dd output:

[image: dd output]

My database:

[image: database]

Comment: you haven't executed the query  `....where(...)->first()`

Comment: @lagbox I'm just stupid sorry

Comment: nah, you just forgot to call `first` ... walk it off champ

Answer (score 1):

To get current category you should;

```php
$currentCategory = Category::where('slug', $category)->first();

dd($currentCategory); // This will output Category model instance or null in case select result is empty
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$currentCategory = Category::where('slug', $category);
```

above query return the builder for fetching the record of the table you should execute query as below

```
$currentCategory = Category::where('slug', $category)->first();
```